# xampp server not responding correctly

Tags: apache2, xampp, nagios3

I had installed the nagios core in UBUNTU os and xamp,nscpp in the windows machine.I tried to monitor the status of the services and all working fine except the services like apache,mysql from xampp server.I tried a lot by changing the port numbers to the servers but the status showing "critical".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30288/discussion-on-question-by-veeru-xampp-server-not-responding-correctly).